# Handle partitioned tables in CakePHP

Tags: postgresql, cakephp, cakephp-3.0, cakephp-2.0, database-partitioning

In my cakephp 3.7.5 app I have a test database in which one of the tables is partitioned as follow:

```
-- Table: public.impressions

-- DROP TABLE public.impressions;

CREATE TABLE public.impressions
(
    id bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('impressions_id_seq'::regclass),
    company_id bigint NOT NULL,
    ad_id bigint,
    seen_at timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
    site_url text COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    cost_per_impression_usd numeric(20,10),
    user_ip inet NOT NULL,
    user_data jsonb,
    CONSTRAINT impressions_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT impressions_company_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (ad_id, company_id)
        REFERENCES public.ads (id, company_id) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
WITH (
    OIDS = FALSE
)
TABLESPACE pg_default;

ALTER TABLE public.impressions
    OWNER to postgres;

-- Rule: impressions_one ON public.impressions

-- DROP Rule impressions_one ON public.impressions;

CREATE OR REPLACE RULE impressions_one AS
    ON INSERT TO public.impressions
    WHERE new.company_id < 25
    DO INSTEAD
INSERT INTO impressions_one (id, company_id, ad_id, seen_at, site_url, cost_per_impression_usd, user_ip, user_data)
  VALUES (new.id, new.company_id, new.ad_id, new.seen_at, new.site_url, new.cost_per_impression_usd, new.user_ip, new.user_data);


-- Rule: impressions_three ON public.impressions

-- DROP Rule impressions_three ON public.impressions;

CREATE OR REPLACE RULE impressions_three AS
    ON INSERT TO public.impressions
    WHERE new.company_id >= 50
    DO INSTEAD
INSERT INTO impressions_three (id, company_id, ad_id, seen_at, site_url, cost_per_impression_usd, user_ip, user_data)
  VALUES (new.id, new.company_id, new.ad_id, new.seen_at, new.site_url, new.cost_per_impression_usd, new.user_ip, new.user_data);


-- Rule: impressions_two ON public.impressions

-- DROP Rule impressions_two ON public.impressions;

CREATE OR REPLACE RULE impressions_two AS
    ON INSERT TO public.impressions
    WHERE new.company_id >= 25 AND new.company_id < 50
    DO INSTEAD
INSERT INTO impressions_two (id, company_id, ad_id, seen_at, site_url, cost_per_impression_usd, user_ip, user_data)
  VALUES (new.id, new.company_id, new.ad_id, new.seen_at, new.site_url, new.cost_per_impression_usd, new.user_ip, new.user_data);
```

All the rules are working correctly and the values are inserted properly in their partitions, but only when I do an `INSERT INTO` sql command.

The problem with my partitioned table and cakephp is that cakephp seems to retrive the inserted entity using the *RETURNING* option after sql *INSERT*

This is from cakephp debug

> INSERT INTO impressions (company_id, seen_at, site_url,
>   cost_per_impression_usd, user_ip, user_data) VALUES (:c0, :c1, :c2,
>   :c3, :c4, :c5) RETURNING *

and of course when I run this query in postgres raises the same exception as the cakephp

> ERROR: cannot perform INSERT RETURNING on relation «impressions»
>   HINT: You need an unconditional ON INSERT DO INSTEAD rule with a
>   RETURNING clause. SQL state: 0A000

the problem is that postgresql does not allow this kind of scenario with returning data, but this is the cakephp way. I did it with symfony, same database, and all worked fine.

Is this cakephp beahvior changeable or configurable in a way that when I do the save for an entity it skip the returning option for the insert. something like:

```
$this->Impressions->save($impression,['skip_returning_stm'=>true]);
```

I need the table partitioned and the cakephp framework, I only tried on symfony in order to discard framework compatibility.

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: tried something with the afterSave event?

Comment: The save event is not triggered as the entity is not beign saved in database due to the exceptions. afterSave and afterSaveCommit events are only fired after the insertion, which is not happening.